# Why does my project result in the "More than one component matched on this element." error?

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I have the following project in a StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/github/nickhodges/PhillyCCTodoApp/tree/Step20

I get this error:

```
Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
```

I have googled my little heart out, but can't seem to find a solution.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

I should note that the error only occurs in StackBlitz and not on my local machine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Angular we **can't have two components on the same element**.

The error states that Angular compiler found two components that match `<mat-form-field` element.

Also it points to the module where it happened.

> ng:///InputControlsModule/EmailInputComponent.html@1:2

And prints those conflicting components:

> MatFormField,MatFormField

Since those components have the same name it can mean only one:

You somehow imported in `InputControlsModule` two different modules that export `MatFormField` directive.

Looking at your module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class InputControlsModule {}
```

I noticed that you imported `MatFormFieldModule` and also `MatInputModule` that export `MatFormFieldModule`(https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/8050f633b56b6c048fc72dad2ab79304afdfad19/src/lib/input/input-module.ts#L29)

But you may think: I read documentation and it shouldn't be a problem since Angular caches once imported module:

[What if I import the same module twice?](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice)

Now, take a look at how you imports those modules:

```
import { ...MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
                                        |
                                material.umd.js

import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
                                                  |
                                         material-form-field.umd.js
```

As you can guess since those modules from different js files they are different.

So in order to fix it you should import them from the same bundle.

```
import {
  ...
  MatInputModule,
  MatFormFieldModule 
} from '@angular/material';
```

But since `MatInputModule` already exports `MatFormFieldModule` you do not need to import it.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vbcbgn?file=src/app/input-controls/input-controls.module.ts)**

Answer (score 6):

Just in case anyone else runs into this with testing, I had the same component mocked out two different ways in the same test by accident. Both mocks had a selector on them. The testing failure output was unclear regarding the origin of the conflict. I spent a bunch of time looking through the  trying to figure it out. Hope this saves someone else an hour or two :|

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was trying to clear some test and didn't see that the component I wanted to mock was already in the imports ...